# Inconsistent character ordering when using spaces around dots?

Tags: bug, status-declined, diff

## [Revision](https://superuser.com/posts/348691/revisions)

So, what did I do to this post? I removed any spaces before comma/point and made sure there was one space after each comma/point. But I am seeing inconsistent results when checking the edit summary...

I know this is a minor edit but this is an example to make clear what I saw happen in other posts.

*Every image is clickable, check them out...*

### Wrong, it thinks that I replaced the space after the comma:

[image]

Should instead show that I removed the space in front of the comma.

### Wrong, it thinks that I replaced the space after the comma:

[image]

Should instead show that I removed the space in front of the comma.

### Right, this last one shows my exact changes:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The diff of the rendered version ignores spaces after words, since all they usually do is add noise to the diff. That's precisely the reason why there are two diff views, one of the Markdown source and one of the rendered version.

As I've said [elsewhere](https://meta.superuser.com/a/3849/561),

> There will always be examples where a human being actually looking at the text will find a better diff than an algorithm.

The rendered diff makes some tradeoffs regarding accuracy around whitespace in order to make the diff more *readable*. For character-perfect diffs, use the source diff.